# modify datetimepicker dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am initializing a datetimepicker as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#meeting_datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'LLLL', stepping: 5, enabledHours: [], daysOfWeekDisabled: []}).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Now I would like to enable this datetimepicker and limit the possible selection dynamically depending on user input. I call this function everytime the user changes certain other selections

```
$("#meeting_datetime").datetimepicker({defaultDate: tomorrowsDate, format: 'LLLL', enabledHours: meeting_time_moment.hours(), stepping: 5, daysOfWeekDisabled: weekday_unchecked_value}).prop('disabled', false);
```

The only aspect of this function which works is the disable false statement at the end. The datetimepicker does indeed become editable. However, the daysOfWeekDisabled function doesn't work at all. I am inputting something like this

```
weekday_unchecked_value =  [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

when I do this in the initialization step (first code snipped on the top), it works fine, but the update does not seem to work. Is there a refresh function or anything? I had a look at the docs (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... just use the functions instead

```
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").daysOfWeekDisabled(weekday_unchecked_value)
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").enabledHours([meeting_time_moment.hours()])
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").stepping(60)
```

it seems to me that there should be an easier way, but this is quick and works fine...