# is there any option in datetimepicker to active or highlight specifict days

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ in my project for schedule doctors appointments.

I have completed everything, but one thing I did not find is that I want to highlight the days on which the doctor is available. I want those days to be active and the other days should be inactive or dim.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`disabledDates`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disableddates) option to set disabled dates into the picker.
In the following example, *tomorrow* and *in three days* are disabled:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  disabledDates: [moment().add(1, 'd'), moment().add(3, 'd')]
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply , You are answer is also helpful but My requirements are bit different. I want to disable fully days, e.g if doctors is not available on a day then that day will be disabled. I found help from.                                                                          weekday_unchecked_value =  [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]       $("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").daysOfWeekDisabled(weekday_unchecked_value)
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").enabledHours([meeting_time_moment.hours()])
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").stepping(60)

Comment: Maybe you have to edit your question to clarify what you have to do (Disable given days? Or disable given weekdays?) Consider adding code example to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem from this article it was helpfull for me.                                   weekday_unchecked_value =  [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[modify datetimepicker dynamically with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515423/modify-datetimepicker-dynamically-with-javascript)     $("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").daysOfWeekDisabled(weekday_unchecked_value)
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").enabledHours([meeting_time_moment.hours()])
$("#meeting_datetime").data("DateTimePicker").stepping(60)